# why is my arraylist out of bounds (index 3, size 3) when I call this method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find a book in an arraylist of books by using the book's name. 
When I try to add a book that's not in the book arraylist, it gives me the arrayoutofbounds exception index:3, size:3.... how can I fix that ?

```
  public Book findBookByName(String bookNameToFind)
   {
    boolean found = false;
    String bookName;
    int index = 0;

    while(!found)
    {
        bookName = bookLibrary.get(index).getTitle();

        if(bookName.equals(bookNameToFind))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return bookLibrary.get(index);
```

Comment: if size is 3 max index is 2

Comment: LOL. I think you should be reading an intro to programming book. You will be asking alot of question on SO otherwise

Comment: You have no limit on how high index goes.  You should never be trying to get the book at an index the size of the ArrayList or greater.  This is definitely a situation you should be using a `for` loop, not a `while`.

Comment: Indexes starts from `0`, so if there are `3` elements their indexes are `0,1,2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use index here and just iterate through your arraylist.

I inverted equals because don't know if title of the book is mandatory in your model.

```
public Book findBookByName(String bookNameToFind) {
    for (Book book : bookLibrary) {
        if (bookNameToFind.equals(book.getTitle()))
            return book; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop:

```
   public Book findBookByName(String bookNameToFind)
   {    
        for (int i = 0; i < bookLibrary.Count(); i++) {
            if (bookLibrary.get(i).getTitle().equals(bookNameToFind))
                return bookLibrary.get(i);
        }

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't find the book, then your index is going to run off the end of the list.  You can either do the for loop like sanghas26 suggested (which is the best solution), or you can add a check at the beginning of the loop to see if `i` has gone too far.